# JPA is not creating any table - IDE Netbeans

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have an implementation which should create a table in mysql. This is just for testing the function of the code.

But it dosen't and I don't know why, my classes looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Shop {
    private List<Artikel> sortiment = new ArrayList<Artikel>();
    private static Shop instance = new Shop();


    public Shop() {    
    Artikel a = new Artikel();
    a.setId(1);
    a.setName("Samsung");

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("onlineshop");
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.persist(a);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

This Class is my Managed Bean class.

And this one is my Persistence Unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="onlineshop" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/onlineshop"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="benjamin"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="start123"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
</properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my Entity-Class look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Artikel implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

So as you can see, it's a very small piece of code, but it won't work for me.
All necessary libraries are included, also the mysql.jar file.

**EDIT**

This are my included jars

[image]

Comment: can you just try with create for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto? beauce create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.

Comment: Does your mysql user 'benjamin' have sufficient privileges to create tables in the database?

Comment: Oh also, with create-drop the database gets dropped when your application is done. So it's possible that you are creating the table, but then when your code has finished running the table is deleted, because that's what create-drop does. switch to create or update.

Comment: The DB user "Benjamin" has admin rights. I have change the property to "create" but still nothing happend...

Comment: you mentioned sql is true so in logs create quey is displaying ??